# Selection Changed IsPostBack or refresh

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, selecteditem, selectionchanged, ispostback

Is there a way for a `SelectionChangeEvent` to get refreshed after selecting an item? I'm having trouble on my windows phone application.

Here is the scenario, I have three items in my combo box, when you select an item it will navigate to a page. Now, if I select Item 1 I will be navigated to Item 1 page, but if I hit back button, then click Item 1 again, it will not navigate anymore or the event does not fire.

Is there a remedy for this please? I have wasted 3days to resolve this. Thanks much in advance for the help. Thanks.

Comment: when you hit back button, can't you modify the `selectedItem` of the `combobox` to a proper value?

Comment: @Bolu No I cannot modify the selected item when I hit the back button. Is there a way to refresh or something like get the memory cleared after selecting an item? thanks